# jsdoc definitions not showing in vs-code or webpack build output

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, webpack, jsdoc

I built a Javascript Library that has jsdoc typings for functions but they don't appear on hover in VS code when I consume that library.
Sample jsdoc'ed function

```js
  /**
   * @param {Object} jsql - Valid query
   * @param {number} [size=20] - Number of rows returned
   * @param {number} [wait=60000] - Query wait time
   * @returns {Object}
   */
  executeJSQL({ size = 20, wait = 60000, jsql }) {
```

I checked that these definitions don't appear in my webpack build `dist/index.js` but, they are included in `dist/index.js.map`. Maybe I am missing something in my webpack config.
Here's my webpack config.js

```js
/* eslint-disable no-nested-ternary */
const path = require('path');
const { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer');
const zopfli = require('@gfx/zopfli');
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');
var JsDocPlugin = require('jsdoc-webpack-plugin');
const NUM_ITERATIONS = 15;
const ASSET_BASE_SIZE = 1024;
const MAX_ASSET_SIZE = 700 * ASSET_BASE_SIZE;
const MIN_ASSET_SIZE = 30 * ASSET_BASE_SIZE;

module.exports = (env = {}) => {
  const config = {
    watchOptions: {
      ignored: ['/node_modules', '/dist', '/coverage', '/__mocks__'],
    },
    mode: env.NODE_ENV || 'production',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
      library: 'XDBCBuilder',
      filename: 'index.js',
      libraryTarget: 'umd',
      path:
        env.DEV_STATUS === 'porting'
          ? path.resolve(
              __dirname,
              env.FROM_PATH,
              'node_modules',
            )
          : env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
          ? path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
          : path.resolve(
              __dirname,
              'node_modules',
'builder'
            ),
      publicPath: '/builder/',
    },
    target: 'node',
    devtool: env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'source-map' : 'eval-source-map',
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.jsx?$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: {
                presets: ['@babel/preset-react'],
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
    optimization: {
      removeAvailableModules: true,
      mangleWasmImports: false,
      nodeEnv: env.NODE_ENV,
      moduleIds: 'size',
      splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'async',
        name: true,
        cacheGroups: {
          vendors: {
            test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
            priority: -10,
          },
          default: {
            priority: -20,
            reuseExistingChunk: true,
          },
        },
      },
    },
    watchOptions: {
      ignored: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'coverage'),
        path.resolve(__dirname, '__mocks__'),
      ],
    },
    performance: {},
    context: __dirname,
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        src: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      },
    },
    node: {
      console: 'mock', // boolean | "mock"
      global: true, // boolean | "mock"
      process: true, // boolean
      __filename: 'mock', // boolean | "mock"
      __dirname: 'mock', // boolean | "mock"
      Buffer: true, // boolean | "mock"
      setImmediate: true, // boolean | "mock" | "empty"
    },
    plugins: [],
  };
  if (env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    config.plugins.push(
      new CompressionPlugin({
        compressionOptions: {
          numiterations: NUM_ITERATIONS,
        },
        algorithm(input, compressionOptions, callback) {
          return zopfli.gzip(input, compressionOptions, callback);
        },
        exclude: [/node_modules/],
      })
    );
    config.optimization.splitChunks.maxSize = MAX_ASSET_SIZE;
    config.optimization.splitChunks.minSize = MIN_ASSET_SIZE;
    config.performance.maxAssetSize = MAX_ASSET_SIZE;
    config.performance.maxEntrypointSize = MAX_ASSET_SIZE;
  }
  if (env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    config.plugins.push(
      new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
        analyzerMode: 'static',
        reportFilename: '../webpack-bundle-report.html',
        openAnalyzer: false,
      })
    );
  }
  return config;
};
```